# Wrong scale/difficult to interpret times on time series object using 'ts'

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data set with energy consumption for every 3 hour interval.

```
 LogDateTime EnergyConsumption
1   2018-10-25 15:00:00       1.379438078
2   2018-10-25 18:00:00       1.171986289
3   2018-10-25 21:00:00       0.020032258
4   2018-10-26 00:00:00       0.020032258
5   2018-10-26 03:00:00       0.020032258
6   2018-10-26 06:00:00       0.020032258
7   2018-10-26 09:00:00       0.477719046
8   2018-10-26 12:00:00       1.127620068
9   2018-10-26 15:00:00       2.177534966
10  2018-10-26 18:00:00       1.091738259
11  2018-10-26 21:00:00       0.020032258
12  2018-10-27 00:00:00       0.020032258
13  2018-10-27 03:00:00       0.020032258
14  2018-10-27 06:00:00       0.020032258
15  2018-10-27 09:00:00       0.020032258
```

I am converting this to time series object using ts in R

```
ts_train <- ts(data = train$EnergyConsumption,start = train$LogDateTime[1],frequency = 56)
```

The head of output ts object is as follows

```
head(ts_train)

Time Series:
Start = c(1540459800, 1) 
End = c(1540459800, 6) 
Frequency = 56 
[1] 1.37943808 1.17198629 0.02003226 0.02003226 0.02003226 0.02003226
```

Here the problem is I am unable to interpret the start and end times of my ts object and also if i plot it as below i am getting a different scale on x-axis

[image]

How can i get the correct start and end times both in ts object and also reflect the same in the plot. BTW, my data starts from "2018-10-25 15:00:00" to  "2018-11-26 18:00:00" with every 3 hour interval in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plot` method for class `ts` isn't very impressive. Now, the x-axis scale hasn't really changed, merely the format has. What you see, those large integers, are the same times as you specified, just represented as [UNIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).
There are ways to make the axis represent time differently, but in the meantime, let me introduce you to the package `zoo`.

Let's say this is your data.frame

```
dtf <- structure(list(time=structure(c(1540472400, 1540483200,
1540494000, 1540504800, 1540515600, 1540526400, 1540537200,
1540548000, 1540558800, 1540569600, 1540580400, 1540591200,
1540602000, 1540612800, 1540623600), class=c("POSIXct",
"POSIXt"), tzone=""), energy=c(1.379438078,
1.171986289, 0.020032258, 0.020032258, 0.020032258, 0.020032258,
0.477719046, 1.127620068, 2.177534966, 1.091738259, 0.020032258,
0.020032258, 0.020032258, 0.020032258, 0.020032258)),
class="data.frame", row.names=c(NA, -15L))
```

As you can see, the first column is in a time format (`POSIXct`). That means we can turn it into a `zoo` object, and then plot it, as simply as

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(dtf)
plot(z)
```

[image]

We can make a sensible plot without `zoo` as well, it just takes a few more lines of code

```
t.ts <- ts(data=dtf$energy, start=as.numeric(dtf$time[1]), frequency=1/(60*60*3))

plot(t.ts, xaxt="n")
time <- as.POSIXct(c(time(t.ts)), origin="1970-01-01")
time <- time[seq_along(time) %% 4 == 1] #select every fourth. less crowded
axis(1, labels=format(time, format="%b %d - %H:%M"), at=time, cex.axis=0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: @AKseIA, Thank you. But I have few questions   
1. Do you think the large numbers in ts are correct for my data?,can  you please point out me to the exact interpretation of those vectors?
2.  May i know those ways to make the axis represent time differently in ts .
 i believe the wrong start & end times in my ts, are affecting my model ( also in all sites  i have seen the different intervaled ts, but haven't came across 3-hour interval )and  can't use zoo here as ets & Holtwinters giving error using zoo object(and even after converting it to ts using as.ts)

Comment: If we do an estimate of how many seconds ago 1970 was, 48*365.25*24*60*60=1514764800, then I'd say those numbers seem reasonable. More details UNIX time in the link I posted. You're right that the end and start times are wrong, and the reason for this is that you're mixing time units. 56 represents a week, but we want that in terms of seconds, not samples, so `f` should be 56/(60*60*24*7), or 1/(60*60*3) if you wish. I know this is messy and confusing, which is why I recommend you to use `zoo` or `xts` instead. At the end of my post I still show how you can do it without these, however.